# isotope - click to expand image and position in top left corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have used the code in the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/zhbLL/3/embedded/result,js,css,html,resources/

but would like to make the selected item the first item so its in the top left corner like the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/8QkEw/

I have merged the JQuery functions from both examples, however, I am struggling getting this to work as am not great with JQuery.  Can anyone help?

```
    <div id="iso-container" class="photos clearfix">
        <div class="photo">
             <a href="People_JJ.jpg"><img src="People_JJ-150x150.jpg" class="small-image" alt="People_JJ"  /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="photo">
            <a href="People_CF.jpg"><img src="People_CF-150x150.jpg" class="small-image"  alt="People_CF"  /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="photo">
            <a href="People_HH.jpg"><img src="People_HH-150x150.jpg" class="small-image"  alt="People_HH"  /></a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="photo">
            <p><a href="People_SF.jpg"><img src="People_SF-150x150.jpg" class="small-image"  alt="People_SF"  /></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    jQuery(function(){

      var $container = jQuery('#iso-container'),
          $photos = $container.find('.photo'),
          $loadingIndicator = jQuery('<div class="loading"><span><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IE7iw.gif" /></span></div>');

      // trigger Isotope after images have loaded
      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
          $container.isotope({
              itemSelector : '.photo',
              masonry: {
                columnWidth: 187
          },
          getSortData : {   //code added from second example
              selected : function( $item ){
                             // sort by selected first, then by original order
                             return ($item.hasClass('selected') ? -1000 : 0 ) + $item.index();
                         }
              },
              sortBy : 'selected'
          });
      });

      // shows the large version of the image
      // shows small version of previously large image
      function enlargeImage( $photo ) {
          $photos.filter('.large').removeClass('large');
          $photos.find('.details').hide();
          $photo.addClass('large');
          $container.isotope('reLayout');
          $photo.children('.details').show();
      }

      $photos.find('a').click( function() {
          var $this = jQuery(this),
              $photo = $this.parents('.photo');

          var $previousSelected = $('.selected'); //code added from second example
          if ( !$this.hasClass('selected') ) {
              $this.addClass('selected');
          }

          $previousSelected.removeClass('selected'); //code added from second example

          // update sortData for new items size  //code added from second example
          $container
              .isotope( 'updateSortData', $this )
              .isotope( 'updateSortData', $previousSelected )
              .isotope();   

          if ( $photo.hasClass('large') ) {
              // already large, just remove
              $photo.removeClass('large');
              $container.isotope('reLayout');
          } else {
              if ( $photo.hasClass('has-big-image') ) {
                  enlargeImage( $photo );
              } else {
                  // add a loading indicator
                  $this.append( $loadingIndicator );

                  // create big image
                  var $bigImage = jQuery('<img>', { src: this.href });

                  // give it a wrapper and appended it to element
                  jQuery('<div>', { 'class': 'big-image' })
                      .append( $bigImage )
                      .appendTo( $this )
                      .imagesLoaded( function() {
                          $loadingIndicator.remove()
                          enlargeImage( $photo );
                      });

                  // add a class, so we'll know not to do this next time
                  $photo.addClass('has-big-image');            
              }
          }

          return false;
      });    
   });
```

P.S.: The above worked in that it would move and open up when selected until I added the code from the 2nd example.  ie the getSortData and the code from var `$previousSelected = $('.selected');`

Comment: can you please show the accompanying html? do you get any result? error messages in the console?

Comment: OK Ive added the HTML.  There are no error messages.  The images just open up the link to the larger image as though the isotope is not working whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this code is missing in your code:

```
...,
    getSortData : {
      selected : function( $item ){
        // sort by selected first, then by original order
        return ($item.hasClass('selected') ? -1000 : 0 ) + $item.index();
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'selected'
...
```

and

```
  $container
      .isotope( 'updateSortData', $this.parent() )
      .isotope( 'updateSortData', $previousSelected )
      .isotope();
    return false;
  });
```

and

```
var $previousSelected = $('.selected');
if ( !$this.parent().hasClass('selected') ) {
  $this.parent().addClass('selected');
}

$previousSelected.removeClass('selected');
```

and

you have to change/or remove the width of your conainer because it is not correct

```
#container {
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 800px;
}
```

this is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ttf5776r/12/)

Comment: Oh I know what it is!  I have been an idiot.  Its is in wordpress and therefore I needed to change the $ to jQuery for the additional code I added. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your second fiddle. Is this http://jsfiddle.net/8QkEw/476/ the expected solution?
**HTML**

```
  <div class="photo">
    <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4131/5013039885_0d16ac87bc.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
   <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4086/5013039583_26717f6e89.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
    <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4144/5013039541_17f2579e33.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
   <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4146/5013646070_f1f44b1939.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
    <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4153/5013039741_d860fb640b.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
   <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039697_a15e41fcd8_b.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
    <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4124/5013646314_c7eaf84918.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
   <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4089/5013040075_bac12ff74e_b.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){


  var $container = $('#container'),
      $items = $('.photo');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.photo',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 60
    },
    getSortData : {
      selected : function( $item ){
        // sort by selected first, then by original order
        return ($item.hasClass('selected') ? -1000 : 0 ) + $item.index();
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'selected'
  })

  $items.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    var $previousSelected = $('.selected');
    if ( !$this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      $this.addClass('selected');
    }

    $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');

    // update sortData for new items size
    $container
      .isotope( 'updateSortData', $this )
      .isotope( 'updateSortData', $previousSelected )
      .isotope();

  });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.photo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:15px 5px;
  float: left;
}
.photo img {
max-width:100%;
}

.photo.selected {
  width: 170px;
  height: auto;
  background: none;
}

/* Start: Recommended Isotope styles */

/**** Isotope Filtering ****/

.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
     -moz-transition-property: height, width;
          transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
          transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}

/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
          transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

/* End: Recommended Isotope styles */